# How to calculate the last month of different years in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with a column "Date" with different months and years.

[image]

I want to calculate the last month of each year. For example for 2018 year, my last month is october but in 2017, the last month is December, etc. How can I get this information?

I need this information because I have an slicer with the date but when I select '2016' the table shows me all the months of each year.

[image]

I want to get something like that:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your pbix file? I am not sure if I understand how this date relates to the data shown in your table in image 2.

Comment: Hello, I can't share my pbix file. Each date represents the total of sales.

Comment: @cneumann, I'm using this formula ThisMonth = if([Date]=MAX([Date]),"Y","N") in order to know the last month, the problem is that applied to all my records. This evaluates the last month in general and I want by year.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you need since I don't have anymore context.  I think what you are missing is the Filter Context vs Evaluation Context. Check [this example](https://neogridsoftware-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/cristhian_neumann_neogrid_com/EZmrfiw3EnRPiJmQr9JlOKIBX3-77RIEAMZP9BLuIHLyYw?e=e5dKdy)